# Changing a pivot table in vba without triggering event handler

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have two pivot tables where the filters in the pagefields I apply to one of them also are applied to the other one. I am doing this with VBA.

I set the event handler for the two pivot tables to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal target As PivotTable)
    Dim Other As PivotTable
    If target.Name = "Component Table" Then
        Set Other = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Categories in Comparison"). _
             PivotTables("Operation Table")
    Else
        Set Other = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Categories in Comparison"). _
            PivotTables("Component Table")
    End If
    Modul2.copyFilters target, Other
End Sub
```

Which calls the sub copyFilters which is defined as follows:

```
Sub copyFilters(source As PivotTable, destination As PivotTable)
    Dim field As PivotField
    For Each field In source.PageFields
        Dim item As PivotItem
        For Each item In field.PivotItems
            If item.Name <> "(blank)" Then
                If (destination.PageFields("Contract Type").PivotItems(item.Name). _
                      Visible <> item.Visible) Then
                    destination.PageFields("Contract Type").PivotItems(item.Name). _
                      Visible = item.Visible
                End If
            End If
        Next item
    Next field
End Sub
```

When I now manually alter the visibility of multiple items, the event handler is called only once, when I press OK after choosing which items to filter for.

But when the above sub is ran, It will trigger the event handler for the other pivot table each time the visibility for one item is changed. This is undesired, since it will change back some of the changes I just manually made.

One solution that comes to my mind is to detach the event handler in copyFilters from the other pivot table while I operate on it and then attach it again. But how can I do that? Or are there other/better solutions to my problem?

Comment: add `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the beggining of event handler `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` and `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the end